# My script only works on desktop not mobile devices.. can you tell me why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a script I use on an html page to hide and show divs depending on what the user clicks.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#solLink").click(function(){
        $(".segSlide").hide(),
        $(".eduSlide").hide(),
        $(".solSlide").show(),
        $(".startOver").show();
    });

    $("#segLink").click(function(){
        $(".solSlide").hide(),
        $(".eduSlide").hide(),
        $(".segSlide").show(),
        $(".startOver").show();
    });

    $("#eduLink").click(function(){
        $(".solSlide").hide(),
        $(".segSlide").hide(),
        $(".eduSlide").show(),
        $(".startOver").show();
    });

});
</script>
```

It works perfectly on my desktop browsers, but when I try it on my iPhone it does not hide/show divs. They are always showing it seems.

Comment: try adding an touchstart event as well. e.g  $("#solLink").on('touchstart click',function(){

Comment: What type of elements are `#solLink`, etc.?

Comment: @Sushil - Thank you! this worked. Thank you to everyone else who replied as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to use [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) for mobile devices. Click events are registered to a mouse where as mobile devices like smartphones and tablets do not.

Try something along these lines:

```js
$(document).on('click touchstart', function () {
    // code here ... 
}
```

There are multiple touch events so the example above may not be the exact event you need, here is the [W3C list of touch events](http://www.w3.org/TR/touch-events/#list-of-touchevent-types).

Comment: Just to add... you can add your selector like this: `$(document).on('click touchstart', '#solLink', function () { ... }`

Comment: "Click events are registered to a mouse where as mobile devices like smartphones and tablets do not"...Is that not browser specific?...I think some of them just translate a click even in a touch event automatically.

Comment: Got it working with a similar solution to this from @Sushil response.

Comment: @Mikey I think you might be referring to [Pointer Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#pointer-events-and-interfaces), here is an [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touchandmouse/) that covers some of what you're asking.

Comment: @hungerstar Thanks I will definetly take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to add this to your code, along with the normal click events:

```
var isMobile=false; 

if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))
            isMobile = true;

$("#solLink").on(isMobile ? 'touchend' : 'click', function(e) {
    //....
});
```

and similarly for other elements.

Comment: But where is `isMobile` defined?

Comment: Oh sorry, I always have it ready for my case though. just edited the answer.

Comment: Just add the condition on the first line of $(document).ready()